# Open/Close submenu when clicking the item name

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I am having problems with the menu part of a wordpress site (salient theme), when i am on mobile, i open the menu with the hamburger button and have several options, some with sub menus, so the items with sub menus only open when clicking the little arrow icon to the right of the item, i am trying to get it to open also when you click on the item itself by making it so when you click the item it triggers a click on the arrow

[image]

here is the html of the menu

[image]

and here is the javascript i am doing to get it to work(only doing it for the first item with submenu here), i am new to javascript but for what i've seen i think this should work (i am using the Code Snippets
plugin for wordpress)

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_footer', function () { ?>
<script>    


var el = (document.querySelector('.menu-item.menu-item-type-custom.menu- 
item-object-custom.menu-item-has-children.menu-item-5812 a'));
console.log(el);    

var el2 =(document.querySelector('.menu-item.menu-item-type-custom.menu- 
item-object-custom.menu-item-has-children.menu-item-5812 span'));
console.log(el2);

el.onclick = function() 
{
    $el2.click();
};

</script>

<?php } );
?>
```

SOLUTION:

aside from the answear by Alvaro Montoro i needed to encapsulate everything inside an eventListener with DomLoaded, here is the final code

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function () { ?>
<script>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

var elSupervivencia = document.querySelector('#slide-out-widget-area > div > 
div.inner > div > ul:nth-child(1) > li.menu-item.menu-item-type-custom.menu- 
item-object-custom.menu-item-has-children.menu-item-5812 > a');
console.log(elSupervivencia);    

var elSupervivenciaFlecha = document.querySelector('#slide-out-widget-area > 
div > div.inner > div > ul:nth-child(1) > li.menu-item.menu-item-type- 
custom.menu-item-object-custom.menu-item-has-children.menu-item-5812 .ocm- 
dropdown-arrow i');
console.log(elSupervivenciaFlecha);

elSupervivenciaFlecha.onclick = function() {
console.log("Clicked on the span");
}

elSupervivencia.onclick = function(e) 
{
e.preventDefault();
elSupervivenciaFlecha.click(); 
};
    });
</script>

<?php } );
```

Comment: But isn't "the item itself" a link to a page? How would users be able to reach that page then?

Comment: @leonidas56 are you a Spanish-speaking developer? you may want to visit [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com) too :)

Comment: @digijay nope, it isnt a link to a page, its just used for the submenu in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you seem to want, you almost have it. The only thing that seems to be missing is to prevent the default behavior when you click on the link (which could be a potential problem as pointed on the comments above, because the linked page may be innaccessible through the menu now).

With [`.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) you will prevent the default action for that element for that event, so you would just need to add that:

```js
var el = (document.querySelector('.menu-item.menu-item-type-custom.menu-item-object-custom.menu-item-has-children.menu-item-5812 a'));
console.log(el);

var el2 = (document.querySelector('.menu-item.menu-item-type-custom.menu-item-object-custom.menu-item-has-children.menu-item-5812 span'));
console.log(el2);

el2.onclick = function() {
  console.log("Clicked on the span");
}

el.onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  el2.click(); // removed the $
};
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-5812">
    <a href="#">Supervivencia</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="super1.html">Supervivencia 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="super2.html">Supervivencia 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="super3.html">Supervivencia 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <span class="ocm-drowndown-arrow" style="top: 17.5px">
      <i class="fa-angle-down"></i>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As they pointed in the comments, that may not be too usable, as the linked page is no longer accessible on the menu, you may want to add some conditions (checking for window size or a variable/class that indicates that the mobile menu is active) to perform that `preventDefault()`.

Apart from that, you may want to consider changing the selector for `el` and `el2`, as they are not specific and could match more than one element. I know you are using `querySelector` so only the first element that matches the selector will be returned, which should not be a problem for `el` but could be problematic with `el2` (because the `a` could be a child `span` that would be selected over the sibling one that is the one you want.)

Comment: Dont worry about the usability as there is nothing linked to the items with submenus, they only work as submenus, no it isnt working tho, so i changed a bit of stuff, so i the selector looks like this now
 
"document.querySelector('#slide-out-widget-area .inner-wrap .inner .off-canvas-menu-container.mobile-only .menu .menu-item.menu-item-type-custom.menu-item-object-custom.menu-item-has-children.menu-item-5812 a');"but that just displays "null" in the console

Comment: Sorry about that, it was missing a dot  but is still doesnt working even tho the console knows exactly what i am selecting

Comment: @leonidas56 I updated the example (there was a new line that broke it) and made it runnable. You can see how when the main link is clicked, instead of doing the default action, it runs the click of the span.

Comment: still not working, now i get the message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null" in the line of el2 and in fact the console is returning null when i log el2

Comment: @leonidas56 edit your question to add a [mcve] where the error can be seen. It is working fine on the demo above, and without seeing your code, it would be impossible to help any further.

Comment: nevermind, just solved it, i just needed to add an eventlistener for DOMContentLoaded, it seems i was acting before the arrow icon was loaded